# Is there any way to look up the controller and method names from a request in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

When I'm in an Action block, how do I figure out which controller is calling me?

In Play 1.0, you could get this information directly from the request object. Is there any way of doing this in Play 2.0 without reparsing conf/routes?

```
def myAction = {
   implicit request =>
       Logger.info("The controller name is " + <cname>)
       Logger.info("The method name is " + <mname>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get that info generically, but if you only need to check for a couple of specific routes then this is how I've done it:

(this is in Java but maybe you or someone can translate to Scala)

```
String requestPath = request().path();
String routeHome = routes.Application.index().toString();

if (requestPath.equals(routeHome))
{
  // user is on Application.index()
}
```